# Disable day and specific date in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to disable day (Monday to Sunday) and specific date in angularJS. Currently I'm using [UI Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker). Everything works but when I scrape my data from API, the data won't work or the API performs massive calls in order to work.

```
<datetimepicker ng-change="dateChanged(date, mode)" 
 ng-model="date" hidden-time="true" hidden-date="false" 
 disabled-date="false" show-button-bar="false" 
 date-options="dateOptions" date-format="EEE, MMM d, y" 
 date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)"></datetimepicker>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.isDisabledDate = function(currentDate, mode) {
   // This will disable Every Monday & Tuesday and the specific date.
   // 0: Monday, 1: Tuesday ... 6: Sunday
   return mode === 'day' && (currentDate.getDay() == 0 || currentDate.getDay() == 1) 
            || ($filter('date')(new Date(currentDate),"yyyy-MM-dd") == "2017-05-15");
}
```

**API Disable Day**

```
"delivery_day": {
   "monday": 0,
   "tuesday": 0,
   "wednesday": 1,
   "thursday": 1,
   "friday": 1,
   "saturday": 1,
   "sunday": 1
}
```

> It shows that every Monday and Tuesday are off-days

**API Disable Date**

```
"disabled_dates": [
    "2017-07-11"
]
```

**Problem**

> isDisabledDate function will be called many times when the page initiated. I have no idea how to parse the "API Disable Day" into that function without let API calls more than once.

Checkout Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Aow7CXFvQUYiMICUgU9T

Comment: create a plunker with your code if possible?

Comment: @tanmay https://plnkr.co/edit/Aow7CXFvQUYiMICUgU9T

Comment: can you state your problem clearly?

Comment: @tanmay I had delivery_day objects. How can I parse the data to $scope.isDisabledDate function?